# Word suggestion in search box

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, search, jquery-autocomplete

In google's search box, as user types a partial term, a list of terms partially matching the term pop up and user might choose one from them. This turns out to be convenient. Please see the attachment:

[image]

Is this done through browser's cache? I guess so, because I observed this on my local machine with my own experimental application. Please see attachment below:

[image]

As I type letter 'a', three words pop up, but my application is super simple, with only a h:form in JSF in front, with much backend to support this in particular. So, I think the three words must be suggested by browser's cache, since I typed them before. Can someone confirm this?

Now, if I want to something similar to the suggestion, but different. The suggested terms are not suggested through Browser's cache, but through a back bean to provide this.

```
<h:form id="wordForm">

    <h:inputText id="word" value="#{wordController.word}" />                        
    <h:commandButton id="search" value="search!"
        action="#{wordController.search}" />
</h:form>
```

For example, if I have a backend bean to hold a map:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class WordSuggestion {

   ...
   private Map<String, String> wordSuggestions;

   public void initialize() {
       wordSuggestions.put("book", "books");
       wordSuggestions.put("book", "booking");
       wordSuggestions.put("book", "booked");
   }
}
```

After the user types the full word "book", I want to 3 candidates "books", "booking" and "booked" to be suggested, in a similar fashion as the above suggestion. One difference is that, for the browser cache suggestion (if it is), as soon as the user types one character, suggestions start; however, in my case, I would want the user to type the full word, i.e. "book", then start the suggestion. Eventually, I also want as soon as the user starts to type, the suggestion starts, but I feel this might be the first type.

How to achieve this in my search box? I am using JEE, JSF, JavaScript, html.

Comment: use query autocomplete plug-in.

Comment: Do you have a link to the plugin? Thank you. And how do I build my own word suggestions into it?

Comment: check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/

Comment: So you can build your own word suggestion words into the autocomplete logic. Right?

Comment: yea Right. you can check that fiddle without angularjs. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/9R4cV/

Comment: Sounds very cool. If my word suggestions may be very large and needs to be stored in a database, would that still be working?

Comment: Yes it's working. Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/32Bck/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105086/discussion-between-ling-and-sumanta736).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this:

```
<input type='text' title='Tags' id='tags' />

$(document).ready(function() {

var aTags = ["ask","always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet","force9", "westerners", "sport"];

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: aTags
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a JQuery autocomplete plugin like [EasyAutocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/)